# How to sort a regex match in PowerShell by a value of the groups array

Tags: regex, powershell

I have an array of strings and each string includes a number which represents the sprint (scrum) number. Now, I want to sort the array by the sprint number using regular expressions in Powershell.

Example of the array

- a.sprint-100
- a.sprint-99
- a.sprint-49
- a.sprint-98

```
# define the array
$a = @("a.sprint-100","a.sprint-99","a.sprint-49","a.sprint-98")

# escape hard defined string in regex
$escapedString = [regex]::escape(".sprint-")

# create regex which matches <AnyCharacter>.sprint-<SprintNumber>
[regex]$regex = "(.+)$escapedString([0-9]{2,3})"

# process the regex on all strings and print out the sprint number
$a | %{[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($_, $regex)} | %{$_.Groups[2].value}

# output: 100 99 49 98

# but my sort logic doesn't work
 $a | %{[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($_, $regex)} | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Groups[2].value} -Descending | %{$_.Groups[2].value}

# output: 99 98 49 100
```

I am sorting on a string. So, this could be the main problem. 
Have anyone an idea to parse the match value to an int?

If I try to do it, then I'm getting `'value' is a ReadOnly property."`.
Or is there a better way to get to my desired sorting result?

For simplification, I used here a string array. But in the real scenario, it is an array including custom objects with a bunch of data. This array should be sorted after my regex pipe.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to sort on the numeric part of the strings, converted to `[int]` first, because otherwise, the sort will still be alphanumeric:

```
# define the array
$a = "a.sprint-100","a.sprint-99","a.sprint-49","a.sprint-98"
# sort on the numeric part of the strings, converted to [int]
$a | Sort-Object {[int]($_ -split '-')[-1]}
```

Result:

> ```
> a.sprint-49
> a.sprint-98
> a.sprint-99
> a.sprint-100
> ```

Comment: This looks like a lightweight solution. I will try it for my use case and mark it as answer if it works. Thank you.

Comment: I need to use regex to filter invalid naming conventions. I combined it with your answer:

$a | %{[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($_, $regex)} | ?{$_.Success} | Sort-Object {[int]($_.Groups[2] -split '-')[-1]} | %{$_.Groups[0].value}

Comment: @o_boo Great stuff! You only showed a small string array as example so there was no way for me to see what else you needed to do with the regex and grouping of the elements. Glad my answer helped in figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a | %{
  [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($_, $regex)} | %{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      sprint=[convert]::ToInt32($_.Groups[2].value,10)
      name=$_.Groups[0].value
    }
  } | Sort-Object -Property {$_.sprint} | Select -ExpandProperty name

# Output a.sprint-49 a.sprint-98 a.sprint-99 a.sprint-100
```

Maybe a little bit to complicated, but it works for string.